# Telegram bot not sending message with "<" , ">" symbols

Tags: python, html, telegram

```
response=requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/<botToken>/sendmessage?chat_id=12345&parse_mode=HTML&text={}".format(" &gt;")) 
print(response.text)
```

The message `>` doesn't get sent on mobile and `response.text` prints  :

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message must be non-empty"}
```

I have followed the telegram official  api https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style -

```
All <, > and & symbols that are not a part of a tag or an HTML entity must be replaced with the corresponding HTML entities (< with &lt;, > with &gt; and & with &amp;).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your text using the python [`urllib.parse.quote_plus(string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) so the special characters won't interfere with the url;

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

response=requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendmessage?chat_id=12345&parse_mode=HTML&text={}".format(quote_plus(" &gt;")))
print(response.text)
```